# action method with parameter in Controller can't be accessed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This is my EmployeeController, I don't understand why I can access url as Employee/Index/1

```
namespace MVCDemo.Controllers
{
    public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult index(int departmentId)
        {
            EmployeeContext employeeContext = new EmployeeContext();
            List<Employee> employee = employeeContext.Employees.Where(emp => emp.DepartmentId == departmentId).ToList();

            return View(employee);
        }

        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            EmployeeContext employeeContext = new EmployeeContext();
            Employee employee = employeeContext.Employees.Single(emp => emp.EmployeeId == id);

            return View(employee);
        }

    }
}
```

**/Employee/Index**      //of course doesn't work, fair enough,

**/Employee/Index/1**   //why it doesn't work? isn't it the same as details action method?

/Employee/Details/1  //worked

/Employee/Index?departmentId=1 //worked but why /Index/1 doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find the code where you configure the routes. Most likely, Visual Studio generated some code for you and put it in the method `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes`.

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

The third item in the list will be mapped to a parameter called `id`. The name you choose for your method parameters is important: asp.net mvc will use reflection to detect your parameter names, and match these to values set in the route configuration.

If you changed the name of the parameter in your `index` method to `id`:

```
    public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
       ...
    }
```

then `id` will match the name referenced in `MapRoute`, and your code will work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you have not changed `RouteConfig.cs`

For `Employee/Index/1` to work you need to have:

```
public class EmployeeController : Controller
{

    // Employee/Index/1
    public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        EmployeeContext employeeContext = new EmployeeContext();
        List<Employee> employee = employeeContext.Employees.Where(emp => emp.DepartmentId == departmentId).ToList();

        return View(employee);
    }

}
```

Btw: You said `/Department/Details/1 //worked`. I guess you mean `/Employee/Details/1 //worked`

Answer (score 0):

Employee/Index/1 works only if your parameter name is **id**

so your action method must be like this:

```
public ActionResult index(int id)
```

of course you can try to change the default routing(controllerName/actionName/id)

Comment: If you are guessing something it means you are not sure what is the problem - in this case post comment (when you get to 50+ rep).

Comment: Please provide explanation why you don't recommend changing routing - doing so is quite regular activity in ASP.Net MVC. In current state it is strange recommendation and thus post deserves downvote.

Comment: this was my first answer here in this site , ok i changed it

Comment: by the way i had used the word must in the next sentence

Comment: i dont reccommend changing the default routing because the default one is enough in most cases and trying to change it usually has nothing but only wasting time.

Comment: i only care if my site is working fine i dont care by which urls it works and i dont try to expend the urls which can map to my action methods.

Comment: I see your reasoning - you may want to edit it into the answer (also I don't see it as good recommendation)...

Comment: recommendation is my opinion every one can have different opinion

Comment: You should be very clear in the post when you express you own opinion vs. providing recommendations based on facts. Something like "I personally would not do .... because ..." is much better than "I don't recommend".

Comment: I removed the last sentence ( recommendation ) by the way i have used many different routings  in my projects , but here i don't see the profit.